# e.preventDefault not working when I trigger it from Submit button but working when triggered from onSubmit attribute in Form tag in React

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a function handleSubmit which contains `e.preventDefault()`.

`e.preventDefault()` works when I call it from `onSubmit` attribute of `<form>` like so:

```
<form className="popup" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

but not working when I trigger handleSubmit from `onClick` attribute in `Submit` button like so:

```
<button className="submit-btn" type="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

`handleSubmit()` function:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var today = new Date();
    const newUser = {
      id:
        today.getHours() +
        ":" +
        today.getMinutes() +
        ":" +
        today.getMilliseconds(),

      username: name,
      email: email,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons do not have a submit event. Try this

```
<button className="submit-btn" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
```